# How can I support a multi-tenant system by programmatically switching DBs depending on the request?

Tags: sails.js

*This question has been ported across from GitHub issues:*

At run time, I would like to specify the database connection to use once the HTTP request has been authenticated (via a policy). What is the best approach to achieve this goal?

For example, a GET request with a header of "tenant_id: smith" is received in order to list all users (e.g. /users). I wish to now switch to the "smith" Mongo DB to query and return the relevant data for that tenant.

*Response from particlebanana:*

Right now this isn't supported out of the box. A "connection" is attached to a collection and is sent down to register itself with the adapter, in your case sails-mongo.

There has been some discussions, mainly around the postgresql adapter, to allow the dynamic selection of a schema in a query. This would attach some optional parameter on the query criteria object that could be parsed by an adapter. It's not something we have started yet though. Once v0.10 is finally released and out of beta we can take a pass at this and come up with a good solution.

For now the only solution I can think of is a custom adapter that wraps the sails-mongo adapter to dynamically select the database to use.

Answer (score 2):

Warning: This turns out to be a potentially dangerous approach - instead we create a set of models per tenant: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo/issues/130

I made some progress and seem to have an implementation working now, through this method:

- I forked the sails-mongo adapter to create a sails-mongo-multi adapter which I set as the default for all the relevant models (i.e. the ones that need to be multi-tenanted).
- Inside adapter.js, in the registerConnection function I load all the DB configs for each tenant and create a new Connection for each (passing in that tenant's config). This happens at startup, so for now I will expect to restart Sails when I add a new tenant.
- I created a switchDB function that accepts a tenant ID and will iterate through each Collection object and update the connection contained within.
- I also update the top-level connection object (which is used when calling native queries).

Will post an update here if I find anything brittle, or broken.

Comment: awesome!  This sounds like a great start.  In general, right now Sails adapters are defined to work with a statically configured set of connections.  But I'd love to see support for this make its way into core eventually-- our team just hasn't run into use cases like this, so it'll probably have to come from the community for now.  Which is why what you're doing is so great :)

Answer (score 0):

I have submit a Pull Requested to [Waterline](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/) to resolve this issue.
See https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/pull/787

I hope this helps and can be merged soon! I'd love to hear any feedback from the community.